# How to use a for loop with an if statement

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement

I'm new to programming and have a problem with figuring this out:

```
clear all
close all
clc
x = [2 * rand(10)-1];
y = [2 * rand(10)-1];
p_i = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2)
n = 0;
for k = 1:100
  if p_i <= 1
    n = n + 1
  end
end
n
```

It gives me the answer `n = 0`. My intention is to make it count how many of the 100 times `p_i` is smaller than 1. I have two questions:
How do I fix this problem? But more importantly how is MATLAB reading my code?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what your exact intentions are.

`rand(10)` produces a matrix `10x10` with random number uniformly distributed between `0` and `1`. So `p_i` is matrix `10x10` and when you do the comparison `p_i<=1` you get another matrix, with logical values, which you can sum up.

```
x = 2*rand(10)-1;
y = 2*rand(10)-1;
p_i = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2);
n = sum(sum(p_i<=1))
n = sum(p_i(:)<=1) % from @XiangruiLi
n = sum(p_i<=1,'all') % from @CrisLuengo, requires MATLAB 2018b
```

Alternatively you can write is with a vector instead of a matrix;

```
samples = 100;
x = 2*rand(samples,1)-1;
y = 2*rand(samples,1)-1;
p_i = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2);
n = sum(p_i<=1)
```

**Second Question**

The `for` loop does not work cause you will need to specify which index to look at:

```
for k = 1:100
    if p_i(k) <= 1
        n = n + 1
    end
end
```

For the statement `p_i <= 1` to be true each of the values of the matrix must satisfy the condition.

Comment: New feature in MATLAB R2018b: `sum(p_i<=1,'all')` -- I'm pretty stoked, I have to let everyone know about it. :)

Comment: you could do n = sum(p_i(:)<=1), looks a little simpler

Comment: @XiangruiLi That is a cleaver way, i always want to add that to the `(p_i<=1)(:)` similar to how it would work  in python, but that does not work in matlab.
@CrisLuengo that is neat thanks

Comment: Thanks everyone for your fast response. I do however still have one question why doesn't my loop work. I ask this because I try to understand what I can do with commands like 'for', 'if' and while'.

Comment: @BjornvanBraak extended the answer

Comment: @BjornvanBraak If you are happy with any of the answer please mark them as answered to make sure the questions gets closed ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your for loop is running 100 times.  Everytime the loop encounters `p_i <= 1`, it is evaluating the statement as `False` and not entering inside the `if` statement.  The statement is `False` because `p_i` contains values greater than `1`, and thus, the matrix as a whole cannot be evaluated as being less than 1.

To better understand how your code is running, you can create a breakpoint at your `p_i <= 1` line before you run your script.  Then once your breakpoint has been hit and your code is paused, you can Step through each line of code.

Answer (score 2):

You have to select the k_th value of the p_i matrix. Something like that:

```
clear all
close all
clc
x = [2 * rand(10)-1];
y = [2 * rand(10)-1];
p_i = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2);
n = 0;
for k = 1:100
  if p_i(k) <= 1
    n = n + 1;
  end
end
n
```